# Combining mayavi and matplotlib in the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, mayavi

I will be making animations. In each frame I want to contain both a mayavi plot obtained with

```
mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(source, some other superfluous args)
```

and a matplotlib plot obtained using simply

```
pylab.plot(args)
```

I have scripts to do both separately, but have no idea how to go about combining them into one figure. I want the end product to be one script which contains the code from both the scripts that I currently have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no direct way because the backends used are so different. It does not seem possible to add `matplotlib` axes to `mayavi.figure` or vice versa.

However, there is a "kind of a way" by using the the `mlab.screenshot`.

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create and capture a mlab object
mlab.test_plot3d()
img = mlab.screenshot()
mlab.close()

# create a pyplot
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.plot([0,1], [1,0], 'r')

# add the screen capture
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.imshow(img)
ax2.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

This is not necessarily the nicest possible way of doing things, and you may bump into resolution problems, as well (check the size of the `mayavi` window). However, it gets the job done in most cases.

Comment: Do you know ways of improving the screenshot resolution?

Comment: @Dennis: The only way I know is to make the Mayavi drawing window as big as possible. And - of course - do this on a screen with as much resolution as possible. (Yes, I would love to have genuine vector output from Mayavi into matplotlib, as well.)

Comment: @Dennis I added an answer with code you can add to set resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by DrV which helped me a great deal, you can work with the mlab figure to set resolution before screenshot such as with batch plotting:

```
mfig = mlab.figure(size=(1024, 1024))
src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(field_3d_numpy_array)
mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src)
iso_surface_plot = mlab.screenshot(figure=mfig, mode='rgba', antialiased=True)
mlab.clf(mfig)
mlab.close()

# Then later in a matplotlib fig:
plt.imshow(iso_surface_plot)
```