# Plot 2d line diagram in mayavi

Tags: python, matplotlib, mayavi

I have a dataset of a tennis game. This dataset contains the ball positions in each rally and the current score. I already 3d-visualized the game and ball positions in mayavi.

Now I want to plot 2d line diagrams in mayavi that visualizes the score developement after specific events (such as after: a break, a set-win, set-loss,...).

I came up with some ideas, but none of them are satisfying:

- I could use imshow and "draw" the diagram
- I could use points3d to plot the diagram
- Maybe I can somehow use pyplot to plot the diagram, then make a screenshot und then plot this screenshot in mayavi...  Any idea if this is possible?

Do you have any other idea how I could plot a 2d line diagram in mayavi?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768179/combining-mayavi-and-matplotlib-in-the-same-figure?rq=1)? It isn't very hopeful, but it might save you some dead ends.

Comment: Yes, but what I need it the other way around... import a 2d diagram screenshot into mayavi

Answer (score 0):

Mayavi is not really good at plotting 2d-diagramms, you can cheat a little by setting your camera position parallel to an 2d image. If you want to plot 2d-diagramms try using matplotlib.